# DB2 Replace issue?

Tags: database, db2, db2-400

Replace Function -- REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(T_DIM5,CHAR(13),' '),CHAR(10),' '),'|',' ') T_DIM5,

Carriage Return and Line feed and Column separator
yes in DB2 not working ..it is replacing actual characters

Oracle it's working fine.

Comment: Could you add more code and actual and expected result? Is it not working from what you expect or what is documented?

Comment: If your database lives on i-series, or on Z/OS  then verify the CCSID of the table/column/tablespace  - if the encoding is for EBCDIC then your code is not valid. You can also show the HEX value of the data in the column before your replace to verify your assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHAR(13) & CHAR(10) return '10' and '13'...

If you're trying to specify hexadecimal literals, then use x'13' and x'10'

Note however, that the data is probably in EBCDIC.  The hexadecimal codes for EBCDIC characters are different than ASCII.